# Start menu items not responding

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, mouse-click

I have a problem with start menu. Whenever I click any icon in start menu, it staying as it is. Usually in normal systems, after clicking the start menu disappears and corresponding program opens. However, in my case the program is opening but start menu is not disappearing and also not recognizing the click.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Test both of the keyboards "windows" & "menu" key items, enter any more information about thier operation into your question.

Answer (score 2):

This may be happen because of virus. Install antivirus software and scan your computer. This might solve your problem.

Comment: I am currently using updated Avast free antivirus. I have scanned the PC, no viruses are found.

Comment: then there might be some windows service which running into it..
you can check in Task Manager.

Comment: The last option is that, you can do recovery of operating system or else format it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the start menu just needs a bump to "refresh" the UI to actual state.

Try toggle Settings-->Personalization-->start-->"Show More Tiles on Start"

Then come back and toggle it back.

You can try toggling other Start settings also - I think you get the idea - you're just trying to "nudge" the Start Menu to refresh itself from the database.

This solved a problem for me whereby an icon did not respond to click at all.